# Discord.py how to make bot reply to multiple messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm new to coding and I was following a tutorial on how to make a bot and it left off with one response, and I was wondering how to add additional response options to the bot; here is the code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hello":
        await message.channel.send("hi")
```

Answer (score 1):

For the case of simplicity, you can just add additional `elif` *(short for else-if)* statements below the `if` statement so that it triggers additional conditions if the initial `if` statement is not met; this way you can write a variety of different options that the message should be matched with until a result (or no result) is found.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hello":
        await message.channel.send("hi")
    elif message.content == "how are you":
        await message.channel.send("I'm doing good!")
    elif message.content == "stackoverflow?":
        await message.channel.send("Here you go! - https://stackoverflow.com")
    else: # What should happen if none of the cases above were met.
        await message.channel.send("I don't understand what you mean :(")
```